# Typescript - Properly typing a map of functions that have bind run on them

Tags: typescript, function, dictionary, typescript-generics

I'm trying to setup typings that allow me to have code completion for a set of functions in a map that have the same variable bound to them without having to manually declare an interface describing the output.

I can do this with a single function just fine (see the `performBind` typings below), and I can get the typings to identify the key inside the map and know that it's a function, but it always has the signature `(...args: any[]) => void`

```ts
// Removes the first param from a tuple of params
type Tail<T extends any[]> =
  ((...args: T) => any) extends ((head: any, ...tail: infer R) => any) ? R : never;

// The input to the map function type
type ActionMapping<A, F extends (...args: any[]) => void>  = {
  [key in keyof A]: F
};

// The output from the map function type.
type PostActionMapping<A, F extends (...args: any[]) => void>  = {
  [key in keyof A]: (...args: Tail<Parameters<F>>) => ReturnType<F>
};

// Single binding function - basically what is being applied to each function in a map, but for a single function
function performBind<F extends (...args: any) => any>(func: F, binding: any): (...args: Tail<Parameters<F>>) => ReturnType<F> {
  return func.bind(null, binding);
}

// Mapping function
function associateActions<A, F extends (...args: any[]) => void>(actions: ActionMapping<A, F>, toBind: number): PostActionMapping<A, F> {
  const actionList: PostActionMapping<A, F> = {} as  PostActionMapping<A, F>  ;
  Object.keys(actions).forEach(key => {

    if (typeof actions[key as keyof A] === 'function') {

      actionList[key as keyof A] =  performBind(actions[key as keyof A], toBind);
    }
  });

  return actionList;
}

// Single function mapping test
const testing = performBind((numberArg: number, stringArg: string): string => {
  return `${numberArg} - ${stringArg}`;
}, 3);

testing('test'); // types as `testing(stringArg: string): void` - Correct!


// My action map
const myActions = {
  testing: (numberArg: number, stringArg: string): string => {
    return `${numberArg} - ${stringArg}`;
  },
};

// Testing w/ my map above
const mapped = associateActions(myActions, 3);
mapped.testing('test'); // types as `mapped.testing(...args: any[]): void` - Missing the typing
```

As noted, the ones coming out of the map are all typed as `(...args: any[]):void`. Everything *works*, but it'd be great of course to have the autocomplete and typings correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typing I'd use for `associateActions()` is as follows:

```
declare function associateActions<
  V,
  O extends Record<keyof O, (a0: V, ...args: any) => any>
>(
  actions: O,
  toBind: V
): {
  [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends (a0: V, ...args: infer A) => infer R
    ? (...args: A) => R
    : never
};
```

It's usually easier to infer a bare type parameter from a value of that type than it is to infer from a value of some function of that type.  So instead of having `actions` be `ActionMapping<A, F>`, I just have it as `O`.  Yes, [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) is a thing, but it's still not as reliable as just inferring `O` from a value of type `O`.  I've [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) the type of `actions` to be a mapping from keys to functions of at least one argument, where the first argument must be of type `V`, the same type as `toBind`.  The return type maps `O` to a [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) type which strips the first argument off each property.  It's equivalent to something like `(...args: Tail<Parameters<O[K]>>) => ReturnType<O[K]>`.

You, uh, do want the return type of the properties to be the return type of the original function, right?  I'm not sure why you want to use `void`, but you don't have to.

I'll leave it up to you to get the implementation of `associateActions()` to type check (you might want to just use a single-call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)).

But let's test the typings:

```
// My action map
const myActions = {
  testing: (numberArg: number, stringArg: string): string => {
    return `${numberArg} - ${stringArg}`;
  }
};

// Testing w/ my map above
const mapped = associateActions(myActions, 3);
// const mapped: (stringArg: string) => string
const str = mapped.testing("test"); 
// const str: string;
```

Looks reasonable to me... `myActions.testing` takes a `number` and a `string` and returns a `string`, so `mapped.testing` takes just a `string` and returns a `string`.  Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXygGdCcwsoMQBBTXVQgHgFgAoeeANQBpX2B5eCAAelVMELwASuBwxgDANYgAnjkTw+XeAAooABgBcnLQDozsAOaEjUVMoCU8ALwA+AnZesX23gVp5rDR42eAwcACEsMSMOVnsjAG9fAG0AaXgo+CVVdT4AXSM+NLzBERAxCV1DY3gzE0tAqMQQGHgqR1cM1GbWyV92AH4dOoajduc3PpD2I1QQADcW1gBfAG5WVgB6TfgAWWU-bDx4AFsoAAdWMACMU+UaI-pneCSQykJsVAsjbVRkE4ARi0qDBvvA-oCWloPjAohYQWCYXD4vAkV8Ji9+vA4BhkDB8AADAAkCQhQJgCOW8AAtPASWj4aDlgT1iFlitWVsdgAVEAfOHwADuOxOBzO5wIAJwiyuN1OF3OIGAzyIJDIFGo-no2lFDzohC0AGZ7KztvBrvRbuLFcAfgyEUYGR03AzZZbURhWk55ecbSZ3p8LNoAEQB4MmrnmuUwx2euGsoA)

Comment: That works perfect! And yeah, the `void` return was probably changed during some iteration of me trying to make it work properly. Thanks a ton!